# CSS command not working in CSS file but working in main HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a website using HTML 5 and I am trying to assign a certain height to a nav element. In the CSS file that I wrote, the height of the element did not change:

```
nav {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100% 
  height: 5%;
  background-color: white; 
}
```

However, when I went into the HTML file and did it again, it did:

```
<style>
    nav {
        height: 5%;
    }
</style>
```

Any way to fix this while still using the CSS file?

Comment: syntax is correct, so use dev tools in the browser to identify what is overriding your rules

Comment: No syntax is not correct. It's a css syntax error, just before height property, after width: 100% you need to add a semi column

Comment: Sometimes browser cache is the problem. Try force reloading using Shift+F5 in chrome to see if something changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just a syntax error:

```
nav{
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%; <~~ you should put semi column at the end of each line
 height: 5%;
 background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Any css style you want to make stronger, make it like this:

```
nav{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 5% !important;
}
```

Comment: Using !important keyword is not recommended. The problem in this case is just a syntax error

Comment: Terrible idea. This can cause major headaches down the road. It exists and works, but if you have to use it there is likely something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: syntax error? first time heard, It's been always used without any issue.